# Using a for loop to create new datasets in the environment

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to use a for loop to filter a large dataset by year. I then want to create new datasets in the global environment that I can use for further calculations.

## creating list of years

```
years <- c("2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012")
```

## for loop

```
for (i in years) {
  pill_[[i]] <- tract_pills %>%
  filter(year == i)
  print(paste0("Finish ", i)
}
```

I can get this to work, but it doesn't create the datasets for each year. It only create the dataset for the last year.

Comment: it is recommended not to create multiple objects in global env.  You can keep it in a list.  if you want, use `assign`

Answer (score 2):

As @akrun says, splitting into a lot of objects isn't a great idea, so keep them in a list. [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) has a function that does just that.

First, I load the library, set the random number generator seed, and create some dummy data.

```r
# Load library
library(data.table)

# Set RNG seed
set.seed(-1)

# Create dummy data
dt <- data.table(year = sample(2010:2019, 20, replace = TRUE),
                 values = runif(20))
```

The data look like this:

```r
# Peak at data
dt
#>     year     values
#>  1: 2014 0.39776012
#>  2: 2011 0.96993492
#>  3: 2019 0.38070385
#>  4: 2011 0.61255114
#>  5: 2012 0.24757823
#>  6: 2015 0.27762129
#>  7: 2013 0.34467428
#>  8: 2018 0.41104418
#>  9: 2013 0.57036917
#> 10: 2012 0.01701321
#> 11: 2017 0.08455335
#> 12: 2012 0.70820147
#> 13: 2012 0.17986181
#> 14: 2015 0.13952228
#> 15: 2012 0.72047842
#> 16: 2019 0.76211781
#> 17: 2010 0.37023226
#> 18: 2010 0.39598003
#> 19: 2013 0.31291316
#> 20: 2017 0.43134829
```

Next, I `split` by `year`:

```r
# Split into a list
split(dt, by = "year")
#> $`2014`
#>    year    values
#> 1: 2014 0.3977601
#> 
#> $`2011`
#>    year    values
#> 1: 2011 0.9699349
#> 2: 2011 0.6125511
#> 
#> $`2019`
#>    year    values
#> 1: 2019 0.3807038
#> 2: 2019 0.7621178
#> 
#> $`2012`
#>    year     values
#> 1: 2012 0.24757823
#> 2: 2012 0.01701321
#> 3: 2012 0.70820147
#> 4: 2012 0.17986181
#> 5: 2012 0.72047842
#> 
#> $`2015`
#>    year    values
#> 1: 2015 0.2776213
#> 2: 2015 0.1395223
#> 
#> $`2013`
#>    year    values
#> 1: 2013 0.3446743
#> 2: 2013 0.5703692
#> 3: 2013 0.3129132
#> 
#> $`2018`
#>    year    values
#> 1: 2018 0.4110442
#> 
#> $`2017`
#>    year     values
#> 1: 2017 0.08455335
#> 2: 2017 0.43134829
#> 
#> $`2010`
#>    year    values
#> 1: 2010 0.3702323
#> 2: 2010 0.3959800
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: Then the OP could use `list2env`. But, like you (@akrun) say, it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing and I come up with the following.

```
library(gapminder)
cont <- unique(gapminder$continent)
df <- NULL
for(i in 1:(length(cont))) {
  temp <- gapminder[gapminder$continent == cont[i], ] 
  df[[i]] <- temp
}

df
```

Answer

```
       [[1]]
    # A tibble: 396 x 6
       country     continent  year lifeExp      pop gdpPercap
       <fct>       <fct>     <int>   <dbl>    <int>     <dbl>
     1 Afghanistan Asia       1952    28.8  8425333      779.
     2 Afghanistan Asia       1957    30.3  9240934      821.
     3 Afghanistan Asia       1962    32.0 10267083      853.
     4 Afghanistan Asia       1967    34.0 11537966      836.
     5 Afghanistan Asia       1972    36.1 13079460      740.
     6 Afghanistan Asia       1977    38.4 14880372      786.
     7 Afghanistan Asia       1982    39.9 12881816      978.
     8 Afghanistan Asia       1987    40.8 13867957      852.
     9 Afghanistan Asia       1992    41.7 16317921      649.
    10 Afghanistan Asia       1997    41.8 22227415      635.
    # ... with 386 more rows
    
    [[2]]
    # A tibble: 360 x 6
       country continent  year lifeExp     pop gdpPercap
       <fct>   <fct>     <int>   <dbl>   <int>     <dbl>
     1 Albania Europe     1952    55.2 1282697     1601.
     2 Albania Europe     1957    59.3 1476505     1942.
     3 Albania Europe     1962    64.8 1728137     2313.
     4 Albania Europe     1967    66.2 1984060     2760.
     5 Albania Europe     1972    67.7 2263554     3313.
     6 Albania Europe     1977    68.9 2509048     3533.
     7 Albania Europe     1982    70.4 2780097     3631.
     8 Albania Europe     1987    72   3075321     3739.
     9 Albania Europe     1992    71.6 3326498     2497.
    10 Albania Europe     1997    73.0 3428038     3193.
    # ... with 350 more rows
.
.
.
.
. continues till the end of the unique continents.
```

if you want to save it with names

```
for(i in 1:(length(cont))) {
  temp <- gapminder[gapminder$continent == cont[i], ]
  #colnames(temp) <- paste0(paste(cont[i]))
  name <- paste0(paste(cont[i]))
  df[[name]] <- temp
}

df$Oceania
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lapply, e.g., with mtcars:

```
cyls <- c(4, 6, 8)
df_list <- lapply(cyls, function(x) filter(mtcars, cyl==x))
```

gives you a list of filtered data frames.